# SCAMMED and LOST 5000 DOGE COIN! Please HELP!

Tags: dogecoin

I was scammed, all my DOGE was taken. I had a stuck pending transaction, I reached out to trust wallet support, they cancelled the pending and then sent the DOGE to a DIFFERENT ADDRESS and not my DOGE address. Is there anything I can do? Its confirmed, but unspent.  Can I track it down somehow or ask for it back? or cancel the sent?

Comment: This is a Bitcoin Q&A website so Doge is off-topic. It sounds like you were tricked by an imposter. I expect there is no way to get your money back.